# Laravel 10 Cors Issue on React app from subdomain

Tags: php, reactjs, laravel, cors, laravel-10

Hi I am facing a very common issue yet can't solve which is cors issue in Laravel 10. I am trying to access from React app installed in subdomain. It seems the login is working fine but after authentication no other route is not working. Here is my cors config file:

```
'paths' => ['*', 'sanctum/csrf-cookie'],

    'allowed_methods' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],

    'allowed_headers' => ['*'],

    'exposed_headers' => [],

    'max_age' => 0,

    'supports_credentials' => false,
```

**kernal.php**

```
protected $middleware = [
        // \App\Http\Middleware\TrustHosts::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies::class,
        \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\HandleCors::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
    ];
```

all code seems ok to me but not working and having issues:

> admin:1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://example.xyz/api/admin/dashboard/' from origin 'https://demo.example.xyz' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request.

**and headers on the network tab:**

> Request URL: https://example.xyz/api/admin/dashboard/
> Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin

Comment: @jub0abs any solution ?

Comment: Not beyond what the error message is already telling you. A 3xx status is not acceptable for the response to a preflight request. You need to find out what's causing that redirect and get rid of it.

Comment: i have solved the preflight issue and preflight request is success but still the issue persist. can you please help ?

Comment: If an issue persists, the error message you're now getting must have changed. What does it say now?

Comment: thanks it resolved and your suggestion helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to first remove the trailing slash from the api url to get rid of from preflight issue and then needed to config the the cors.php config file as below:

```
'paths' => ['api/*', 'sanctum/csrf-cookie'],

'allowed_methods' => ['*'],

'allowed_origins' => ['*'],

'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],

'allowed_headers' => [':authority:', ':method:', ':path:', ':scheme:'], // this is the line i needed to update to solve the issue.

'exposed_headers' => [],

'max_age' => 0,

'supports_credentials' => false,
```

and worked like charm !!

Answer (score 1):

try adding this in env with valid url

```
SESSION_DOMAIN=localhost
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=localhost
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using API endpoints for react to consume then add

```
'paths' => ['api/*', 'sanctum/csrf-cookie'],
```

Another very common scenario is **missing permission** on the storage folder leading to CORS error. You can set proper permission to the storage folder.

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data path_to_your_project
```

Comment: this doesn't help much